# Understanding proof of properties for integral of simple functions

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $(X,\scr{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $L^+$ be the collection of all $\scr{M}$-measurable functions from $X\to [0,\infty]$. Let $f,g$ are simple functions then $\int(f+g)=\int f +\int g$.

I understand the proof but one part of it I have some doubt.

The proof starts with let $f=\sum^na_j1_{E_j}$ and $g=\sum^kb_i1_{F_i}$ be the canonical form where $n,k$ are finite. Then we have for each $j$, $E_j=\bigcup^k(E_j\cap F_i)$ and for each $i$, $F_i=\bigcup^n(F_i\cap E_j)$. I understand why we need above equalities involving finite union, but my question is what guarantees the intersections of those unions are all non-empty? Since we are taking finite unions. If the intersections are all empty, then the equality won't hold.

I must be missing something logics, can anyone point it out? many thanks!

Comment: I suppose canonical form means all the sets are disjoint and partition the space? Then there must be intersection, right?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you , I didn't know canonical form means that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we can express the function $f$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}1_{A_{i}}(x)
\end{align*}
where the collection of sets $\{A_{1},A_{2},\ldots,A_{m}\}$ is partition of the sample space $X$.

Similarly, we can also express the function $g$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
g(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}1_{B_{j}}(x)
\end{align*}
where the collection $\{B_{1},B_{2},\ldots,B_{n}\}$ is a partition of the sample space $X$.

Consequently, it is possible to rewrite the formula of the function $f$ as:
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}1_{A_{i}}(x)\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}1_{A_{i}}(x)1_{X}(x)\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}1_{A_{i}}(x)\sum_{j=1}^{n}1_{B_{j}}(x)\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{n}1_{A_{i}}(x)1_{B_{j}}(x)\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{i}1_{A_{i}\cap B_{j}}(x)
\end{align*}

In the same fashion, one gets that:
\begin{align*}
g(x) & = \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}1_{B_{j}}(x)\\
& = \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}1_{B_{j}}(x)1_{X}(x)\\
& = \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}1_{B_{j}}(x)\sum_{i=1}^{m}1_{A_{i}}(x)\\
& = \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}\sum_{i=1}^{m}1_{B_{j}}(x)1_{A_{i}}(x)\\
& = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m}b_{j}1_{B_{j}\cap A_{i}}(x)\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}1_{A_{i}\cap B_{j}}(x)
\end{align*}

Based on such consideration as well on the integral definition of simple functions, we have that:
\begin{align*}
\int(f + g)\mathrm{d}\mu & = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_{i} + b_{j})\mu(A_{i}\cap B_{j})\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{i}\mu(A_{i}\cap B_{j}) + \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m}b_{j}\mu(A_{i}\cap B_{j})\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu(A_{i}\cap B_{j}) + \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\mu(A_{i}\cap B_{j})\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}\mu(A_{i}) + \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}\mu(B_{j})\\
& = \int f\mathrm{d}\mu + \int g\mathrm{d}\mu
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Nice. The $A_i$ and $B_j$ both form partitions. The sets $A_i\cap B_j$ some "pseudo-partition" in the sense that they are still disjoint and covering but some of them might be empty. Maybe that's the thing that bothered the OP. Your answer makes clear that this fact is not really an obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. **Some** intersections may be empty, but still it is impossible that **all** of them are empty.

The latter is impossible, because $\bigcup_i F_i = \bigcup_j E_j =X$.

More formally, let $E$ be any set and suppose by contradiction that $E\cap F_i =\emptyset$, **for all $i$**.

Then $E = (E\cap \bigcup_i F_i) = \bigcup_i E\cap F_i = \bigcup_i \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Therefore, if the intersection is empty for all $i$, then $E=\emptyset$. It is impossible that all of the $E_i$'s are empty because then $X = \bigcup_i E_i = \emptyset$.