# Proving $\int (\phi + \varphi) d{\mu} = \int \phi d{\mu} + \int \varphi d{\mu} $

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In Rick Durrett Probability Theory 1.4 Integration,

let  $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(\Omega, \mathbb{F})$

also let $\int \phi d{\mu} = \sum_{i=0}^m a_i \mu(A_i)$

when proving  $\int (\phi + \varphi) d{\mu}  = \int \phi d{\mu} + \int \varphi d{\mu}  $, where $\phi = \sum_{i=0}^m a_i \mathbb{1}_{A_i}$, $\varphi = \sum_{i=0}^n b_i \mathbb{1}_{B_i}$, $A_i$ are disjoint sets ($B_i$ same), $ A_i \bigcap B_j$ are pairwise disjoint

I don't understand why it let $A_0 = {\bigcup}_i B_i - {\bigcup}_i A_i$, $B_0 = {\bigcup}_i A_i - {\bigcup}_i B_i$ and let $a_0 = b_0 = 0$?  Why can't it just start from i = 1?

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652318/understanding-proof-of-properties-for-integral-of-simple-functions/4652330#4652330) may help you.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia  Thank you for the link. It answers part of my question.

Comment: you are welcome.